# why does Razor put validation attributes in @Html.Hiddenfor() helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

it doesn't make any sense, is there anyway to make this not to act this way? 
for

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)
```

I get

```
<input type="hidden" value="e62fceab-588c-4777-bfe9-8516425a5028" name="Id" id="Id" data-val-required="The Id field is required."  data-val="true">
```

Comment: Why is it a problem that MVC added there the validation attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is automatically adding required validation to all non null-able fields. If you don't like this then you can make your id null-able.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an additional layer of server side protection.  It's trivial to change an outgoing hidden input with a man in the middle tool like Fiddler.

As for making it optional, there's almost surely a data attribute for that.  Alternatively, adding a question mark after the property name in your model should do it.